# how to plot multiplot boxplot in Jupyter notebook by using Altair library

Tags: python, data-science, visualization, altair

```
import altair as alt

ad_type = ["SEO", "Email", "PPC",  "PR", "Direct Mail", "OMB"]
roi = [68.9, 56.7, 52.4, 48.5, 37.4,  19.9]
data = {"adtype":ad_type, "roi":roi}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

alt.Chart(df.melt()).mark_boxplot().encode(
    x='variable',
    y='value'
)
```

by using the upper code i can plot boxplot columns in one figure as this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Cga.png)
how can i change the code to plot these boxplot in two figures separately

thanks

Comment: look at the result of `df.melt()`. I don't think this is the data structure you want it to be

Comment: really i don't have any options can you recommend something to do better really

Comment: don't have enough data for two different boxplots. based on the data you've provided it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. For instance, what values should be along the x-axis?